# Why is csvkit giving me "List Index out of Range" errors?

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with a [zipcode dataset](http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/zipcode.zip) and csvkit, but getting nowhere. If I do `csvcut -n zipcode.csv` I see a clean list of columns:

```
  1: zip
  2: city
  3: state
  4: latitude
  5: longitude
  6: timezone
  7: dst
```

But any searches I do with `csvgrep` just give me an error. Here's a chunk of data:

```
"99919","Thorne Bay","AK","55.677232","-132.55624","-9","1"
"99921","Craig","AK","55.456449","-133.02648","-9","1"
"99922","Hydaburg","AK","55.209339","-132.82545","-9","1"
"99923","Hyder","AK","55.941442","-130.0545","-9","1"
"99925","Klawock","AK","55.555164","-133.07316","-9","1"
"99926","Metlakatla","AK","55.123897","-131.56883","-9","1"
"99927","Point Baker","AK","56.337957","-133.60689","-9","1"
"99928","Ward Cove","AK","55.395359","-131.67537","-9","1"
"99929","Wrangell","AK","56.409507","-132.33822","-9","1"
"99950","Ketchikan","AK","55.875767","-131.46633","-9","1"
```

Per [the docs](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvgrep.html), I expect that `csvgrep -c 2 -m "Hyder" zipcode.csv` will turn up a match, but instead I get:

```
zip,city,state,latitude,longitude,timezone,dst
list index out of range
```

I'm able to use `csvgrep` fine on other csv files -- why is it choking on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is "zipcodes.csv" is malformed; it includes blank lines. For example, line #17 is blank:

```
"00607","Aguas Buenas","PR","18.256995","-66.104657","-4","0"

"00609","Aibonito","PR","18.142002","-66.273278","-4","0"
```

The author of the document may have done this to indicate the postal code 00608 does not exist, which may be helpful in some instances, but is preventing you from using the csvkit utility.

You can use [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), which if you're using *nix-based OS, you already have installed to automatically remove the blank lines like so:

```
$ sed '/^$/d' zipcode.csv > zipcode2.csv
```

This will store the result as "zipcode2.csv". We can now use our new "fixed" postal code file:

```
$ csvgrep -c 2 -m "Hyder" zipcode2.csv 
zip,city,state,latitude,longitude,timezone,dst
99923,Hyder,AK,55.941442,-130.0545,-9,1
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to prevent most errors like the one described, I am using [csvclean](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/scripts/csvclean.html) (also from csvkit) to find and correct corrupted data in the source csv. Also check [this blog post](http://blog.aplikate.eu/2015/01/03/import-csv-data-into-postgresql-the-comfortable-way/) for a complete how-to